# Tomcat/Java - Insert into a mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

```
package mycode;
import java.sql.*
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Login extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4546189621945422719L;

String URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1";
String USER = "root";
String PASS = "1234";

@Override 
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws IOException,ServletException{

}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = req.getParameter("username");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);

        String sql = "INSERT INTO cloud.cloud_table (Username,Password)" +
                "VALUES (?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, username);
        pst.setString(2, password);
        pst.executeUpdate(); 


        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("THANKS FOR CREATING AN ACCOUNT");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Login</display-name>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>mycode.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
```

---

```
+----------+----------+
| Username | Password |
+----------+----------+
|          |          |
+----------+----------+
```

---

```
<form action="login" method="GET">
    <div>
        <h4>Please enter your password and username</h4>
    </div>
    <div>
        Username <input name="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Password <input name="password" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Using java and tomcat, I have a simple form that takes in a username and password. I want to be able to retrieve the username and password from the form and insert it into a mysql database. However, right now after clicking the submit button on the form, nothing happens and the database is not updated. The database connection is working fine so I am not sure what the problem is right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show that simple form code?

Comment: If you click submit and nothing happens, your html form might not be working.

Comment: @alayor I have added the code for the form

Comment: @qwertyayyy your form does not POST the data, it uses GET. So the Servlet's ``doGet`` method is called, which does nothing. Change your html form to ``method="POST"``.

Comment: Urggh such a stupid mistake. Anyway I have corrected it now but i am getting "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1" error. How do I go about fixing this ?

Comment: @qwertyayyy add `mysql jdbc` jar to your build path and `lib` directory in `WebContent/WEB-INF` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling your GET method from the HTML form.

Change your action to POST.

```
<form action="login" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, cant believe i was making such a stupid mistake. Anyway I have corrected it now but i am getting "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1" error

Comment: You need to add MySQL Driver to the classpath. I recommend you investigate on your own about this and open a new question of you can't find anything.